# How to obtain cell value of selected row in SwiftUI Table

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm a SwiftUI Beginner.  I'm now trying to obtain cell value of selected row in SwiftUI Table.  With Cocoa bindings, it is easy.  Just like write as `ArrayController.selection.Name`.  Or using SwiftUI List, I can obtain selection result like the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var listElements = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Forth"]
    @State private var selectedOne: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GroupBox("List") {
            List(listElements, id:\.self, selection: $selectedOne) { element in
                Text(element)
            }
        }
        
        GroupBox("Selection") {
            Text("Selection: \(selectedOne == nil ? "None" : selectedOne!)")
        }
        .frame(minHeight: 300)
   }
}
```

But I can't find out how to do with SwiftUI Table.  Here's my trying Table.  Currently I just get uuid of selected row with `selection.description`:

```
 import SwiftUI

struct Entrant: Identifiable {
    public let id = UUID()
    public var Flags: String
    public var Name: String
    public var Rank: String
    public var Obs: String
    public var Pl: String
    public var Idle: String
}

private var entrantList = [
    Entrant(Flags: "a",
            Name: "Chavez",
            Rank: "1d",
            Obs: "-",
            Pl: "1",
            Idle: "29m"),
    Entrant(Flags: "a",
            Name: "Chen",
            Rank: "1k",
            Obs: "-",
            Pl: "1",
            Idle: "33m"),
    Entrant(Flags: "a",
            Name: "Clark",
            Rank: "10k",
            Obs: "-",
            Pl: "-",
            Idle: "39m"),
    Entrant(Flags: "a",
            Name: "Clark",
            Rank: "10k",
            Obs: "-",
            Pl: "-",
            Idle: "39m"),
    Entrant(Flags: "a",
            Name: "zxH3",
            Rank: "10k",
            Obs: "-",
            Pl: "-",
            Idle: "39m"),
    Entrant(Flags: "a",
            Name: "pkls3",
            Rank: "10k",
            Obs: "-",
            Pl: "-",
            Idle: "39m"),
    Entrant(Flags: "X",
            Name: "xanadu6291",
            Rank: "5k",
            Obs: "-",
            Pl: "-",
            Idle: "0s"),
]

struct ContentView: View {
            
    @State private var entrants = entrantList
    @State private var selection: Entrant.ID? = nil
            
    var body: some View {
                    
        VStack {
            
            Table(entrants, selection: $selection) {
                TableColumn("Flags",value:\.Flags).width(35)
                TableColumn("Name", value:\.Name).width(80)
                TableColumn("Rank", value:\.Rank).width(30)
                TableColumn("Obs", value:\.Obs).width(30)
                TableColumn("Pl", value:\.Pl).width(20)
                TableColumn("Idle", value:\.Idle).width(30)
            }.frame(width: 350, height: 200)
            
            
            Button("Push Me!") {
                let _ = print(selection!.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding this in your button, to get `...value of selected row...` :

```
 Button("Push Me!") {
     let _ = print(selection!.description)
     
     if let item = entrants.first(where: {$0.id == selection}) {
         print("---> item: \(item)")
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I joined together your answer and @sreekuttan 's answer, then get desired value.  I used `item.Name`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [onChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) to observe *selection* value changes.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var entrants = entrantList // your list of items
    @State private var selection: UUID? = nil

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Table(entrants, selection: $selection) {
                TableColumn("Flags",value:\.Flags).width(35)
                TableColumn("Name", value:\.Name).width(80)
                TableColumn("Rank", value:\.Rank).width(30)
                TableColumn("Obs", value:\.Obs).width(30)
                TableColumn("Pl", value:\.Pl).width(20)
                TableColumn("Idle", value:\.Idle).width(30)
            }
            .onChange(of: selection, perform: { selected in
                // called each time on table selection changes

                let item = entrants.first(where: { $0.id == selected })
                print("Selected id : ", selected!)
                print("Selected item : ", item as Any)
            })
            .frame(width: 350, height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My goal is to get the cell value of the selected row, but the `onChange` block was helpful.  Now I could able to get cell value joining together your answer and @workingdog-support-ukraine 's answer.